# Firefox add-on to "alt-tab" for tabs

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

In Windows, when you hit alt-tab, you can browse through open windows. I recall, at one point, there was a similar add-on for Firefox where you could hit a keyboard shortcut and, just like the windows feature, a small window would pop-up where you could view all the open tabs and also navigate and select.

I know I can use ctrl+tab or cmd+(1 through 9), but when I have too many tabs, it's very painful to cycle through all those tabs.

I've done an lengthy search but can't find anything. Does anyone happen to know of this add-on or a similar add-on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were probably thinking of **[Ctrl+Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/ctrl-tab/?src=search)**. The Add-on seems to be outdated, however.

[image]

---

[**Tab Groups**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tab-groups-organize-tabs) is a built-in feature of Firefox and may be useful for you. Helps with tab organization. It's not an add-on, but seems useful for what you're doing.

[**Tile Tabs**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tile-tabs/) may suit your needs also. It lets you view all your open tabs but not in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> Windows type of way.